# Adding OAuth to a Scalatra web service

Tags: scala, oauth, warden, scalatra

I am looking to build a Scalatra based API. One of the requirements is OAuth authentication. I noticed the guide for OAuth isn't yet put up on the official Scalatra site. Is the best way to currently add OAuth support by figuring out how to add an OAuth based strategy into Warden? I come from a Ruby on Rails based background, so new to a lot of Scala/Java conventions. There's probably several ways to tackle this but I'm hoping for any solution that's documented and can be referenced for implementation in my own application.

Answer (score 2):

I am currently rewriting a Ruby/Sinatra app in Scala/Scalatra. I found the easiest way to add OAuth is to use Scribe (https://github.com/fernandezpablo85/scribe-java). There is a guide on using Scribe with Scala here:

https://github.com/earldouglas/nuevos#consuming-the-twitter-api-in-scala-with-scribe

Note that the exact implementation of the Twitter API is outdated. He made some minor updates to the code without actually updating the README (That confused me for some time.) I suggest you read the normal Java Scribe guide first, then take a look at the source code of the Scalatra example.